# Display an html ordered list of array items?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the list displaying, but not displaying in an HTML ordered list. I know I somehow need to create a `<li>` element and attach it to the array. I don't know how to attach the array of items to a `<li>` element. Here is my code thus far.

```
let toDos = ['walk cat', 'pet fish'];
let listItems;

for (let i = 0; i < toDos.length; i++) {
    let displayListItems = document.createElement('li');
    listItems = toDos[i];
    listContainer.append(listItems);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want, it will display in whatever order you list the data in the toDos list. If you're storing the data externally you'll want to attach it by some id you can use to insert it back in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options to do that: `innerText` or `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

```js
const listContainer = document.querySelector("ol");

let toDos = ['walk cat', 'pet fish'];
let listItems;

for (let i = 0; i < toDos.length; i++) {
    let displayListItems = document.createElement('li');
    listItems = toDos[i];
    displayListItems.innerHTML = listItems;
    //displayListItems.innerText = listItems; //or this one
    //displayListItems.textContent = listItems; //or this one
    
    listContainer.append(displayListItems);
}
```

```html
<ol></ol>
```

And notice that `listContainer.append(listItems);` is incorrect and you have to append `displayListItems`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You just need to create a list item using `document.createElement('li')` as you are creating
2. Add it's text using `textContent`
3. Append the listItem using `appendChild` or `append`.

```js
const listContainer = document.querySelector("ol");

let toDos = ['walk cat', 'pet fish'];
let listItems;

for (let i = 0; i < toDos.length; i++) {
  let displayListItems = document.createElement('li');
  listItems = toDos[i];
  displayListItems.textContent = listItems;
  listContainer.append(displayListItems);
}
```

```html
<ol></ol>
```

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Much appreciated.